# Android - fragments don't show

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created one acivity and a few fragments. I try to show one of them after start-up but I see empty screen, without fragments (but with NavigationDrawer)

What do I do wrong?
I have no idea where my mistake is.
Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new DashboardFragment()).commit();
...


public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
...
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.romansytnyk.studentstudio.fragments.DashboardFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:text="Week info \n\n"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from NavigationView also can you show the onCreateView method of DashboardFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should add fragment :

```
FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add([FRAGMENT],[STRING TAG]);
        ft.commit();
```